# Bitmap image to hexadecimal conversion

Tags: bitmap, hex, bmp, file-conversion

I am looking for a development tool which can convert a standard bitmap image into an array of hexadecimal values. Is there such a thing but, if not, how would I go about doing this on my own?

Comment: you can essay write a code that read image file and write output txtfile of hex

Answer (score 0):

If you read the file in blocks you can get the exact data. You can use a structure with header to track the size of the file and actual data present in each block.

This you can do in a simple C program. Btw the file data if you dump in hexadecimal mode you will always see the data in the image will be hexadecimal. Take the block size as 4K or 64K, then the header will not be an overhead.